# How to remove/hide focus-part of nvd3 LineWithFocusChart

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-nvd3-directives

Im using a LineWithFocusChart in my angular nvd3 webapp like [this one](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/lineWithFocusChart). I have a use of hiding/showing the bottom-part of the diagramm dynamically. Is there an option to do so or do I have to replace the LineWithFocusChart with a usual LineChart and vice versa when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the same page you have [linked](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/lineWithFocusChart), you can see `focusEnable` controls the display of the bottom part.

Comment: true. its sad, I spended time implementing another lineWithoutFocusChart and switchting them, when a solution can be that easy.